# building module in dnn need advice with text editor placment not on same line as message

Tags: c#, html, dotnetnuke

I am building a module in DotNetNuke and having a problem with the coding.This is my first time attempting this and It may sound stupid to most but I am newer to this.. Here is what I expect:

```
         Send Mail To: [___________]

         Send Mail From: [__________]

         Subject: [__________]
                   ____________________________
         Message: |                           |
                  |                           |
                  |                           |
                  |___________________________|
```

But Here is what I am getting:

```
         Send Mail To: [___________]

         Send Mail From: [__________]

         Subject: [__________]

         Email Message:
____________________________
|                           |
|                           |
|                           |
|___________________________|
```

Here is my code:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="false" Inherits="Scott.SendEmail.View" CodeFile="View.ascx.cs" %>

<%@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" TagName="Label" Src="~/controls/LabelControl.ascx" %>

<%@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" TagName="TextEditor" Src="~/controls/TextEditor.ascx"%>

<div class="dnnForm dnnEdit dnnClear" id="dnnEdit">

    <fieldset>

        <div class="dnnFormItem">

            <dnn:label id="plField" runat="server" text="SendTo" helptext="Enter a 
            value" controlname="txtField" />

            <asp:textbox id="txtField" runat="server" maxlength="255" />          

            <dnn:label id="plField2" runat="server" text="SendFrom" helptext="Enter a
            value" controlname="txtField" />

            <asp:textbox id="txtField2" runat="server" maxlength="255" />          

            <dnn:label id="plField3" runat="server" text="Subject" helptext="Enter a 
            value" controlname="txtField" />

            <asp:textbox id="txtField3" runat="server" maxlength="255" />


            <dnn:label id="plField4" runat="server" helptext="Enter a value" 
            controlname="txtField" />

            <dnn:TextEditor ID="txtField4" runat="server" />            
        </div>

   </fieldset>

    <ul class="dnnActions dnnClear">

        <li><asp:linkbutton id="cmdSave" text="Save" runat="server" 
        cssclass="dnnPrimaryAction" /></li>

        <li><asp:linkbutton id="cmdCancel" text="Cancel" runat="server"
        cssclass="dnnSecondaryAction" /></li>

    </ul>

 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any reason you're not using a table layout? Its what I've found the easiest way to display the text editor where I want it. If you're opposed to a table layout, you will have to float the containing div that the editor will get rendered wrapped in.

```
<table class="dnnFormItem">
    <tr>
        <td><dnn:label id="plField" runat="server" text="SendTo" helptext="Enter a 
        value" controlname="txtField" /></td>

        <td><asp:textbox id="txtField" runat="server" maxlength="255" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><dnn:label id="plField2" runat="server" text="SendFrom" helptext="Enter a
        value" controlname="txtField" /></td>

        <td><asp:textbox id="txtField2" runat="server" maxlength="255" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><dnn:label id="plField3" runat="server" text="Subject" helptext="Enter a 
        value" controlname="txtField" /></td>

        <td><asp:textbox id="txtField3" runat="server" maxlength="255" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><dnn:label id="plField4" runat="server" helptext="Enter a value" 
        controlname="txtField" /></td>

        <td><dnn:TextEditor ID="txtField4" runat="server" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I am not opposed to it, just ignorant. I do not know how to do that yet.

Comment: I've added some code to put your form in a table layout. It hopefully will have the desired effect.